# Confused about AlertDialog's height behaviour

Tags: java, android

I have a simple AlertDialog shown like so:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Test")
    .setView(R.layout.dialog_test)
    .setPositiveButton("button1", null)
    .show();
```

This is what the `dialog_test` layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:text="Test"/>
```

The TextView shows up positioned at the top of the dialog's content space with extra space beneath it. So it appears that the AlertDialog has some sort of minimum height defined. I would like to get rid of the AlertDialog's minimum height and wrap the height of the TextView or I'd like to at least vertically center the TextView in the AlertDialog's content space.

I have tried setting the dialog's layout to wrap the height before/after it is shown, but it does not do anything: `dialog.window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`

I've also tried setting the TextView's `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content` and `android:layout_gravity` to `center_vertical` but the TextView still stays at the top of the AlertDialog's content space. I tried setting the TextView's `android:layout_height` to `match_parent` and `android:gravity` to `center_vertical` but the TextView's height is not filling the AlertDialog's content space, and appears to remain wrapped and it stays at the top of the AlertDialog's content.

I am using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` but have also tried `android.app.AlertDialog` and it has the same issue.

So is there a way for me to remove the AlertDialog's minimum height or at least center the content vertically when my content's height is less than the AlertDialog's minimum height?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: After looking through AlertDialog's code, I found that the layout (customPanel) where your custom view is added does indeed have a minimum height.

And you can remove the minimum height like so:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(R.layout.dialog_test)
    .show();
dialog.findViewById(R.id.customPanel).setMinimumHeight(0);
// Use R.id.contentPanel if you're using setMessage() instead of setView()
```

Or, if you want to keep the minimum height but want to center the content vertically, I accomplished it like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(R.layout.dialog_test)
    .show();
((FrameLayaout.LayoutParams) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom).getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
```

Comment: use inflater to inflate the layout? i guess that is the problem

Comment: my guess is that the alert dialog is creating space for the buttons that it usually contains.

Comment: Using a LayoutInflater didn't do anything. If I don't define any buttons, or not even a title, there is still lots of unnecessary space beneath the TextView.

Comment: I meant that the alert dialog  might be creating space for buttons even though they may not be defined. Kind of like the difference between `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.GONE`

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I think the AlertDialog's content has some minimum height specified. If I create an AlertDialog and just set the text with `setMessage`, there is a lot of unnecessary space under the message if the message is short. But if I set a long message, there is no unnecessary space.

Comment: Generally, if I just need to inform my user about "anything" and I want a certain "look" I create a custom layout for a `Toast` message. Of course a drawback is that it disappears on its own.

Comment: i have custom alert dialog box with thumb bar (SeekBar) and button, i used wrap content to all. it works fine. Of course there is a space for title and positive buttton but if i remove them, the space they occupy is gone.

Comment: But is your SeekBar fairly large height-wise? I still think there is some minimum height for AlertDialog's content.  I created a brand new project and it's still is showing unnecessary space for the most basic AlertDialog: `AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(R.layout.dialog_test).show()`. Picture here: https://i.imgur.com/4YF6l3d.png